# sleep() await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

why I got the error: wait is only valid in async function

```
const sleep = async ((ms) =>  {
     new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
})

const test1 = async (() => {
    await sleep(1000)
})

await test1()
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your last line `await test1()` is not inside an `async` function. You can replace it with, `( async() => await test1() )()`

Comment: @junvar Thanks !